# Publicar Tweet desde Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, twitter

¿Se puede enviar/postear un **tweet** desde una app creada en **Android Studio**?

En caso de ser posible, ¿Me pueden mostrar un ejemplo? Estuve investigando, lo más cercano que encontré fue este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062419/how-to-use-twitter-api-in-android-application-for-send-tweet-only) pero no es exactamente lo que busco ya que en las soluciones que dan abren `Twitter` o el navegador o lo comparten. A modo de ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos una interfaz con un `EditText` y un `Button`, el mensaje ya va a estar escrito y el `EditText` solo va a contener tu nombre de usuario en `Twitter` y presionando el `Button` se twittea el mensaje pero no sales de la aplicación.

Datos a tener en cuenta:

**Primero:** crear una cuenta **fantasma** en `twitter` para obtener la **API KEY / API SECRET KEY / BEARER TOKEN**, eso está hecho.

**Segundo:** suponiendo que nuestra cuenta fantasma se llama **@EjemploCuentaFantasma** lo que busco es que cuando la persona ingrese su **usuario** personal de **twitter**  en el `EditText` y presione el `botón`, se publique un **tweet** en **@EjemploCuentaFantasma** con el mensaje que diga (por ejemplo) **Hola @UsuarioDelEditText bienvenido**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es algo extensa tu pregunta pero una opciòn para realizar lo que deseas es usar [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/) que es una Java Library para usar la API de Twitter.

http://twitter4j.org/en/

Descarga y copia el `twitter4j-core-[version].jar`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hacia el directorio `/libs` de tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la pàgina de desarrollo para Twitter https://developer.twitter.com/ crea un aplicaciòn y obtèn los valores de API Key y API Secret Key

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la pàgina http://twitter4j.org/en/ puedes ver varios ejemplos pero este es un ejemplo de lo que debes realizar para inicializar Twitter

Debes obtener inicializar usando `API Key` y `API Secret Key` y la url de redirect definida en tu aplicaciòn Twitter para obtener un `RequestToken`.

```
private static Twitter twitter;
private static final String APIConsumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String APIConsumerSecretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
private static RequestToken twitterRequestToken;
private EditText twitterUser;


   private static void initializeTwitter(final Activity activity) {
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(APIConsumerKey);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(APIConsumerSecretKey);
        twitter = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build()).getInstance();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    twitterRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Open Dialog for authentication.
                            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, TwitterAuthActivity.class);
                            if (twitterRequestToken != null) {
                                intent.putExtra("TwitterReqTokenUrl", twitterRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

De esta forma inicializaras la sesiòn

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class TwitterAuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Twitter4j";
    private static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String twitterRequesTokenUrl;
    private WebView twitterWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_twitter);
        twitterWebView = findViewById(R.id.TwitterWebView);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            twitterRequesTokenUrl = extras.getString("TwitterReqTokenUrl");
        }
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        //Setup WebView
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        twitterWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        twitterWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        twitterWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = twitterWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        twitterWebView.loadUrl(twitterRequesTokenUrl);
    }

 }
```

al obtener la sesiòn puedes cargar en un `WebView` la pàgina web de Twitter para realizar el post de tu informaciòn y aquì puedes agregar en la variable `message` el usuario que obtendrìas desde un `EditText`:

```
"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + url + "&text=" + message + "&lang=es"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class TwitterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TwitterActivity";
    public static final String SHARE_URL = "shareurl", MESSAGE = "message", ENCODING_UTF8 = "UTF-8";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private WebView twitterWebView;

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String message = "", url = "";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_twitter);
        twitterWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.TwitterWebView);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TwitterActivity.this);
        WebSettings webSettings = twitterWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        twitterWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwiterWebViewClient());
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        try {
            message = URLEncoder.encode(bundle.getString(MESSAGE), ENCODING_UTF8);
            url = bundle.getString(SHARE_URL);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException "+ e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception "+ e.getMessage());
        }

        twitterWebView.loadUrl("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + url + "&text=" + message + "&lang=es");

        progressDialog.setMessage("Hold on! ... :-)");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    }
```

Esta misma activity puede ser usada para navegar en tu sesiòn `Twitter`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí puedes descargar el proyecto ejemplo:

**https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Twitter4J**

Comment: Eres un genio, ¿Podrías dejarme el enlace en GitHub para verlo más detalladamente? Mil gracias

Comment: Con gusto @FranqoBalsamo, lo agrego a la respuesta, solo modificas el APIConsumerKey, APIConsumerSecretKey, CALLBACK_URL de tu proyecto Twitter.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias :)